# Hyperledger Composer : Create Transaction using JQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, api, transactions, hyperledger-composer

i am creating a front end for my example business network using html and jquery. Thus far i am able to create asset, search and delete asset using the front end.

I am having trouble while creating a asset using a transaction.

This is the business model file

```
namespace org.acme.chequebook

asset Cheque identified by chequeNumber {

o String chequeNumber

}

transaction CreateCheque{
o String chequeNumber
}
```

This is the script

```
 $("#myChequeCreateButton").click(function(){


        var obj={
        "$class": "org.acme.chequebook.CreateCheque",
        "chequeNumber":$("#inputChequeNumber").val(),
        "transactionId":"",
        "timestamp":"",
        }    
        $.post('http://localhost:3000/api/CreateCheque',obj).done(function(res){




        }).fail(function(res){




        })

  })
```

I understand that **transactionId** and **timestamp** are assigned automatically at the time of transaction execution. So i am confused on how i should handle it here.

When i try to submit this **transaction** it produces following error

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/api/CreateCheque 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Comment: try removing the transactionId and timestamp fields, you should not pass those fields at all.

Comment: You were right. It works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

confirming that the answer is to simply remove the fields "transactionId" and "timestamp"